# Standard error of the sum of regressions (linear combination)

Tags: regression, standard-error

Very basic question... Let's say I have 2 independent linear regressions, y1 = a1X + b1, y2 = a2x + b2. For each of these regressions I have a standard error - How can I calculate the standard error for the linear superposition of these regressions y3 = y1 + y2? Keep in mind that the X samples for y1 and y2 are different, therefore, I can't simply sum the terms and compute the new standard error.

Comment: Since the $x$ values are different, could you please explain what 'y1 + y2' even means??

Comment: You are right, I can't really define y3 -- sorry, I guess I didn't give too much detail.
What I'm mainly looking for is a linear combination of the slopes. You can think of an engineering system for which we have different regressions for each individual component, but I'm interested in the total system derivatives (linear superposition of the component slopes). What I'm after is how to propagate the error.

Comment: Please add new information not only in comments, but add it tothe post as an edit.  We want posts to be self-contained, and few people read comments! which also can be deleted